# Outlook addin & custom form region: how do they communicate?

Tags: c#, class, outlook, add-in

I've got two partial classes in the same namespace for my Outlook addin. One is for a custom form region and one is for the addin itself. How can I let these two classes share data? Specifically, `ThisAddIn` needs to get some information from `FormRegion1`.

```
// ThisAddIn.cs
namespace My_AddIn {
    public partial class ThisAddIn {
```

and

```
// FormRegion1.cs
namespace My_AddIn {
    partial class FormRegion1 {
```

I guess my question is really how to get the inspector for FormRegion1 from ThisAddIn. I've tried things like this inside the Inspectors_NewInspector event handler method of the ThisAddIn class:

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
if (mailItem != null) {
    Outlook.Pages page = mailItem.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages as Outlook.Pages;
    // previous line causes unhandled COMException error ("the operation failed")
```

and

```
Outlook.Pages page = Application.GetInspectors[mailItem].ModifiedFormPages["FormRegion1"];
// previous line causes unhandled COMException error ("type mismatch")
```

Does anyone have any insight into the proper way to access FormRegion1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an event whose handler would let ThisAddIn get a reference to FormRegion1 (everything that I found fired before the FormRegion1 was instantiated). I ended up using a singleton to give ThisAddIn a reference to each FormRegion1 instance.

Comment: Do you have an example of your code?  I'm trying the same thing but have no familiarity with writing singeltons.

Comment: @Larry: I abandoned that approach as well because I didn't want to deal with negotiating appropriate instances (otherwise the singleton will only yield the most recent copy of its storage; it breaks on multiple windows). Good example code: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx